# Got a compilation error C2248 when accessing public member of the object theApp

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I got a compilation error C2248: "cannot access protected member declared in class 'CMyApp'". The variable itself is declared as public. What am I doing wrong? Is it common?

I have the following code:
CMyApp.h:

```
class CMyApp : public CWinAppEx
{
public:
    CVWMFCApp();
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
    virtual int ExitInstance();
public:
    BOOL m_bHiColorIcons;
    virtual void PreLoadState();
    virtual void LoadCustomState();
    virtual void SaveCustomState();
    afx_msg void OnAppAbout();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    CStringList slFileContentList;
...
```

CMyApp.cpp:

```
...
CMyApp theApp;
...
```

CChildView.cpp:

```
void CChildView::OnPaint() 
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CStringList slFileContentList = theApp.slFileContentList;
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP` you'll see that it starts with

```
#define DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP() \
protected: \
...
```

So the stuff after `DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP` is also declared `protected`, thus the access problem/compiler error message.

Comment: Thank you, this was the case exactly!

Comment: @tschesseket: [Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers): *"Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. **If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer**, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question."*